# Can't rotate objects in edit mode in Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

So I had this problem before but in Blender 2.79. The problem was that I couldn't rotate objects in edit mode. This happened due to a shortcut i didn't know about. However there is a button in 2.79 with enables you to rotate again.

But in blender 2.8 there is no such button. There are no forums about it. Please help me with a shortcut or where I can locate the button to enable rotation again.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od9jk.jpg

Please tell me how to disable this!

Thank you

Comment: Have you locked the rotation? Select the object tab and check if the lock symbol next rotation values are enabled.

Comment: look in your user preferences to see if it's set to rotate by "r".  Go to Keymap, then 3D View > 3D View (Global), and near the bottom is the rotate shortcut key settings.  It's very specifically labeled:  "rotate".  :)

Comment: @RBlong2us yes of course it is set to r for rotate

Comment: @rjg where can I locate that? Can you please send me a screenshot? I'm relatively new to 2.8. Thank you, you can post the image as an answer

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnoMu.jpg Unless that is activated you should be able to rotate either through shortcut R or the rotate tool in the left toolbar.

Comment: What you have marked red is snap toggle, the key combination is SHIFT + TAB.

Comment: Shift tab doesn't work

Comment: And I know how to rotate it's just it doesn't work

Comment: All we can do is guess, so you either need to upload your blend file or attach a full screenshot that lets us see (at least some) of the options you have selected. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I was in face select mode and my circle doesn't have any polygons...

When I changed to edge select the object rotated.

Thank you for trying to help me. I'm dumb.

Comment: ahh, everyone misses something at one point or another.  At least you figured out the problem!